# Specialized template picked after base - why

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code:

```
template<typename T> struct Container {};

template <int a, int b, typename T = Container<bool>>
struct temp;

template <int a, int b, typename T>
struct temp<a, b, Container<T>> {
    using type = void;
};

int main()
{

    static_assert(std::is_same<temp<0, 1>::type, void>::value, "error");

}
```

my question is: **why is the more specialized template being instantiated??**

I was expecting an error like "can't find definition for temp<0,1,Container>" (for the base template) but instead the more specialized one is being picked.. kind of a "second round of template lookup". How come this happens?

Comment: The more specialized one being picked is kind of the point of template specialization. It would be useless otherwise.

Comment: Yes but I'm baffled at the fact that the parameter list is being considered **before** all the body of the template struct.

Comment: A primary use case of specialization is to provide something that will work when the primary template won't.

Comment: @T.C. thanks, at this point the question is: why are the default arguments *appended* to the parameters list passed to the base template?